# Having issues with rotating/moving objects, as it's selection/pivot point is different from actual object

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, interface, 3d-cursor

Currently following a tutorial for Blender, as I'm still relatively new to it. Ran into an issue where I realized that the actual selection/pivot point of the object, in particular, was moved away from the object. Don't know how to fix this, currently on Blender 2.9x.

[image]

This is what happens when I tell the two parented objects to snap to cursor, which is at World Origin. Object is rotated around this point too. I'd appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Can it be that you have "wrong" mode selected in the Transform Pivot Point menu? At least that affects rotation of parented objects.

Comment: @KarlS When he snaps selection to 3D cursor and his objects are staying away from the cursor while you can see the origin point at the cursor, this cannot be a problem of wrong Pivot Points. It's simply the origin point that's not within the mesh.